# Как вернуть уже существующий объект класса и изменить его?

Tags: java, ооп

```
public class Movie {

    public String name;
    public String description;
    public int price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Movie(String name, String description, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Затем, я создаю объект класса:

```
new Movie(name, description, price);
```

И еще несколько таких объектов с разными данными.

Затем, я хочу изменить данные объектов. Могу ли я это сделать? И где они в данный момент хранятся? Только в оперативной памяти? Есть ли какой-то метод поиска существующих объектов по одному из его полей, указанных в конструкторе?
Или для этого необходимо обязательно где-то сохранить эти объекты, например, в ArrayList? При создании нового экземпляра класса предыдущий экземпляр удаляется из памяти?

Comment: Создаешь переменную-экземпляр данного класса и обращаешься к ней;
Можно создать сколь угодно много экземпляров класса, если он не синглтон.

Comment: @Circassian супер, спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужна ссылка для объекта, чтобы вы могли как-то с ним оперировать. Либо `Movie movie = new Movie(name, description, price);`, либо добавить в список или массив, тогда ссылкой будет соответствующая ячейка: `list.get(0)` или `array[0]` например.

> я хочу изменить данные объектов. Могу ли я это сделать?

Да. У вас для этого в приведённом вами коде есть методы. Например:

```
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

Ничто не мешает вам вызвать этот метод у созданного объекта и передать туда новое значение. Вот так: `movie.setDescription("Голубая луна джунглей")`;

> При создании нового экземпляра класса предыдущий экземпляр удаляется
> из памяти?

Нет. Вы же можете сделать вот так:

```
Movie movie = new Movie("Мир дикого Востока", description, price);
Movie movie1 = new Movie("Принесённые ветром", description, price);
Movie movie2 = new Movie("Вперёд в прошлое", description, price);
```

У вас здесь несколько экземпляров одного класса и вы можете работать с ними одновременно. Но если вы сделали вот так:

```
Movie movie = new Movie("Шестой батальон", description, price);
movie = new Movie("В бегство!", description, price);
```

то есть одной и той же ссылке присвоили сначала первый объект, а потом второй, то первый объект рано или поздно будет уничтожен сборщиком мусора *(при условии, что на него больше нигде нет ссылок)*.

> Есть ли какой-то метод поиска существующих объектов по одному из его
> полей, указанных в конструкторе?

Чтобы что-то искать, вы сначала должны понять, что, как и зачем вы хотите искать. Можно искать в списке. При помощи цикла, например:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).getDescription.equals("Один друг Маушена")) {
        return list.get(i);
    }
}
```

или Stream API:

```
list.stream().filter(m -> m.getDescription.equals("Один друг Маушена")).findFirst();
```

Comment: допустим, я создал переменную `Movie movie1 = new Movie(данные...)`. И таких еще несколько переменных movie2, movie3 и тд.. Теперь я у movie1 хочу изменить поля. Как это сделать? Не могу ведь я взять и использовать метод setName(), как этот метод поймет у какого именно экземпляра я изменяю имя... Напишите код, как изменить movie1 без создания новых экземпляров пожалуйста

Comment: @hot_penguin вы можете использовать setName(). Смотрите. В Java есть статические методы и обычные. Обычные методы могут быть вызваны только у созданного экземпляра класса. Вот так: `movie1.setName("Name")` и, соответственно, обычный метод всегда знает, к какому экземпляру он относится - вы всегда вызываете его у экземпляра, иначе нельзя

Comment: ааа точно... Спасибо

Comment: @hot_penguin статические методы в свою очередь не относятся к конкретному экземпляру класса и вызываются сами по себе. Посмотрите, как выглядит код:
`cat.meow()` - это нестатический метод, вызывается у экземпляра. Cat.meow() - это статический метод, вызывается у класса.

Comment: А можно ли вместо `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).getDescription.equals("Один друг Маушена")) {
        return list.get(i);
    }
}` использовать `for (Movie m : Movies.movieArrayList) {
            if (m.name.equals(name)) {
                return m;
            }
        }` ?

Comment: @hot_penguin foreach? Да, можно, только чуть по-другому: `for (Movie m : movies) {             if (m.getName().equals(name)) {                 return m;             }`. Справа от двоеточия ставите название списка. Я вот поставил movies (допустим, список с названием moview)

Comment: а почему именно пetName(), а не поле name? В чем будет разница

Comment: @hot_penguin можно и name, без разницы. Просто по правилам ООП нельзя оставлять открытый доступ к полям класса. Поэтому их делают private (доступными только внутри класса) и делают методы для доступа к ним.

Comment: А можно ли одной стрчокой изменить сразу все поля объекта? Или 3 раза писать set

Comment: @hot_penguin нет, одной строкой нельзя. Либо сделайте в классе метод, который будет принимать три параметра и устанавливать их в поля экземпляра

Answer (score 3):

> Затем, я хочу изменить данные объектов. Могу ли я это сделать?

Да. У вас в классе объявлены сеттеры (методы вида `setSomething()`). Они предназначены для того, чтобы менять состояния объектов.

> И где они в данный момент хранятся? Только в оперативной памяти?

Да, они в оперативной памяти. При этом, если вы не сохраняли ссылки на эти объекты в переменные, то очень скоро (хотя никто не знает когда) сборщик мусора их удалит.

> Есть ли какой-то метод поиска существующих объектов по одному из его полей, указанных в конструкторе? Или для этого необходимо обязательно где-то сохранить эти объекты, например, в ArrayList?

Ссылку на один объект обычно сохраняют в простую переменную. Например так:

```
Movie mov1 = new Movie("Ирония судьбы", "Новогодняя комедия", 100);
```

Здесь `mov1` -- ссылка на только созданный объект.

Если нужно создать несколько объектов, то их можно сохранить в несколько переменных. А те сложить в один список или один массив, как больше нравится:

```
Movie mov1 = new Movie("Ирония судьбы", "Новогодняя комедия", 100);
Movie mov2 = new Movie("Операция Ы", "Советская комедия", 100);

List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
movies.add(mov1);
movies.add(mov2);
```

Чтобы найти фильм по одному из полей, можно, например, перебрать список (List) фильмов и выбрать тот, поле которого соответствует нужному критерию. Например, найти такой, поле name которого эквивалентно строке "Ирония судьбы".

Для этого есть разные способы и здесь их объяснять долго. Некоторые из них относятся к базовому синтаксису языка и вам просто нужно пройти тему "Циклы" в учебнике.

> При создании нового экземпляра класса предыдущий экземпляр удаляется из памяти?

Нет, ни в коем случае. Объект удалится из памяти только тогда, когда все ссылки на него пропадут из области видимости. Это ещё одна отдельная тема, которую, к сожалению, не раскрыть в рамках комментария.